# Why do I get the error "missing field" when deserializing XML with serde-xml-rs, even though the element is present?

Tags: xml, rust, serde

I have the following XML file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<project name="project-name">
    <libraries>
        <library groupId="org.example" artifactId="&lt;name&gt;" version="0.1"/>
        <library groupId="com.example" artifactId="&quot;cool-lib&amp;" version="999"/>
    </libraries>
</project>
```

I want to deserialize it using serde-xml-rs into this struct hierarchy:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Project {
    name: String,
    libraries: Libraries
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Libraries {
    libraries: Vec<Library>,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Library {
    groupId: String,
    artifactId: String,
    version: String,
}
```

I am trying to read from the file using the below code.

```rust
let file = File::open("data/sample_1.xml").unwrap();
let project: Project = from_reader(file).unwrap();
```

I get this error saying "missing field `libraries`":

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error(Custom("missing field `libraries`"), State { next_error: None, backtrace: None })', src/libcore/result.rs:997:5
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
```

Comment: After looking at your profile page here on SO, I spotted that you rarely accept answers. You should concider doing that (in the future *and* your questions you have already asked). You can do that by clicking the check mark next to an answer answer. That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist (also you gain +2 reputation per accepted question). [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the example at the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/RReverser/serde-xml-rs/blob/e6bf15ae703ff8eb76143d1dcecc445b78e53e07/README.md#Usage), you are missing an annotation:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Libraries {
    #[serde(rename = "library")]
    libraries: Vec<Library>
}
```

With that I get the correct deserialized representation of your XML file

```
project = Project {
    name: "project-name",
    libraries: Libraries {
        libraries: [
            Library {
                groupId: "org.example",
                artifactId: "<name>",
                version: "0.1"
            },
            Library {
                groupId: "com.example",
                artifactId: "\"cool-lib&",
                version: "999"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```